# How do I supply an Expression<Action<T>> in F# when the method has a return value?

Tags: f#, expression, hyprlinkr

I'm attempting to convert some C# code to F#. Specifically, I'm attempting to convert some code using [Hyprlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr) to F#.

The C# code looks like this:

```
Href = this.linker.GetUri<ImagesController>(c =>
    c.Get("{file-name}")).ToString()
```

where the `GetUri` method is defined as

```
public Uri GetUri<T>(Expression<Action<T>> method);
```

and `ImagesController.Get` is defined as

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
```

In F#, I'm attempting to do this:

```
Href = linker.GetUri<ImagesController>(
    fun c -> c.Get("{file-name}") |> ignore).ToString())
```

This compiles, but at run-time throws this exception:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>    HResult=-2147024809
>    Message=Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for return type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit'
>    Source=System.Core

As far as I understand this, the F# expression is an expression that returns `unit`, but it should really be an `Expression<Action<T>>`, 'returning' `void`.

I'm using F# 3.0 (I think - I'm using Visual Studio 2012).

How can I address this problem?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a known bug - could you try it with F# 3.1 in the Visual Studio 2013 preview to see if it still repros?

Comment: See my comment to desco's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it should be fixed in F# 3.1. This is from VS2013 Preview

```
type T = static member Get(e : System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action<'T>>) = e
type U = member this.MakeString() = "123"
T.Get(fun (u : U) -> ignore(u.MakeString())) // u => Ignore(u.MakeString())
```

**UPDATE:** Cannot check with actual library from the question, so I'd try to mimic the interface I see. This code works fine in F# 3.1

```
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions

type Linker() = 
    member this.GetUri<'T>(action : Expression<Action<'T>>) : string = action.ToString()

type Model() = class end

type Controller() = 
    member this.Get(s : string) = Model()

let linker = Linker()
let text1 = linker.GetUri<Controller>(fun c -> c.Get("x") |> ignore) // c => op_PipeRight(c.Get("x"), ToFSharpFunc(value => Ignore(value)))
let text2 = linker.GetUri<Controller>(fun c -> ignore(c.Get("x"))) // c => Ignore(c.Get("x"))

printfn "Ok"
```

**UPDATE 2:** I've peeked into the source code of Hyprlinkr and I guess I've found the reason.
Current implementation of library code that analyzes expression trees is making certain assumptions about its shape. In particular:

```
// C#
linker.GetUri((c : Controller) => c.Get("{file-name}"))
```

1. Code assumes that the body of expression tree is method call expression (i.e. invokation of some method from controller)
2. Then code picks method call arguments one by one and tries to get its values by wraping them into 0-argument lambda, compiling and running it. Library implicitly relies that argument values are either constant values or values captured from the enclosing environment.

Shape of expression tree generated by F# runtime (i.e. when piping is used) will be

c => op_PipeRight(c.Get("x"), ToFSharpFunc(value => Ignore(value)))

This is still method call expression (so assumption 1 will still be correct) but its first argument uses parameter c. If this argument will be converted to lambda with no arguments (() => c.Get("x")) - then method body of such lambda will refer to some free variable c - precisely what was written in exception message.

As an alternative that will be more F# friendly I can suggest to add extra overload for GetUri

```
public string GetUri<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> e)
```

It can be both used on C# and F# sides

```
// C#
linker.GetUri((Controller c) => c.Get("{filename}"))

// F#
linker.GetUri(fun (c : Controller) -> c.Get("{filename}"))
```

Comment: It looks like the actual issue may be with piping, not with `ignore` _per se_.  Does piping to `ignore` also work with F# 3.1?

Comment: @kvb: You're right, `ignore(...)` works in 3.0 too. Now I'm curious why the pipe in my answer works.

Comment: Actually my original answer was with piping (and it works too). I've modified it to get better represented result expression tree

Comment: In F# 3.1, I'm now consistently getting the same error with or without piping: "variable 'c' of type 'ImagesController' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined". In F# 3.0, I only got that error when *not* using piping.

Comment: Update 2 in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help! Fortunately, I also control Hyprlinkr, so I added an overload as you suggested, and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for F# 2.0, you can define your own "ignore" function with a generic return type. This apparently allows `void` to be inferred.

```ml
let noop _ = Unchecked.defaultof<_>

Href = linker.GetUri<ImagesController>(fun c -> 
    c.Get("{file-name}") |> noop).ToString())
```

Comment: It's not that `void` can be inferred; it's that typically functions that return `unit` (including `ignore`) are actually compiled to `void` returning methods; for generic return types this can't be the case (because `void` is not a legal type argument in the .NET type system).

Comment: Yeah, 'inferred' wasn't the right word. But it does create a lambda expression with a `void` return type.

Comment: That gives me another run-time exception: "variable 'c' of type 'ImagesController' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think that you may be able to just call `ignore` without using a pipe:

```
Href = linker.GetUri<ImagesController>(
    fun c -> ignore(c.Get("{file-name}"))).ToString()
```

**UPDATE**

Given desco's diagnosis of HyprLinkr's behavior, it seems like you ought to be able to use a utility along these lines:

```
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions

type ActionHelper =
    static member IgnoreResult(e:Expression<Converter<'t,_>>) = 
        Expression.Lambda<Action<'t>>(e.Body, e.Parameters)
```

Then you can do

```
Href = linker.GetUri<ImagesController>(
    ActionHelper.IgnoreResult(fun c -> c.Get("{file-name}"))).ToString()
```

Comment: That gives me another run-time exception: "variable 'c' of type 'ImagesController' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

Comment: @MarkSeemann - can you include the stack trace?  Is that exception being thrown by the F# runtime or by Hyprlinkr (or something else)?